# TS 2322: typescript and mongoose.model as a return type to a function

Tags: typescript, mongoose

New to typescript. I was trying to create a mongoose model factory that based on a role will return the mongoose model. I will then use this model in Data Access Layer (DAL) to continue with my business layer. The issue is that I am getting the following error. TS2322:type 'typeof(../../model)is not assignable to type 'Model. Property 'findById' is missing in type 'typeof('../../model')

Am I missing an explicit cast?

**model code**

```
import * as mongoose from "mongoose";

let StudentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  id:Number,
  username: String,
  email: String,
  sectors: [{
    sectorName:String,
    QP: String
  }]  
}, {
  timestamps: {
  createdAt: 'created_at'
 }
});

export default mongoose.model('StudentNotification', StudentSchema);
```

**my model factory code ** I get the error in the return StudentNotification code.

```
import * as mongoose from "mongoose";
import * as StudentNotification from './models/student';

export class ModelFactory {
private userRole:string;
constructor(role:string){
    this.userRole = role;
}

Create():mongoose.Model<mongoose.Document>{
    switch(this.userRole){
        case "Student":{
            return StudentNotification;
            break;
        }
        default :{
            return null;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To import the default export you need to use this syntax :

```
import * as mongoose from "mongoose";
import StudentNotification from './models/student'; // HERE !

function Create():mongoose.Model<mongoose.Document>{
    switch(this.userRole){
        case "Student":{
            return StudentNotification;
        }
        default :{
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Or if you use the * syntax then you have to write it like this:

```
import StudentNotification from './models/student';
... 
      return StudentNotification.default;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your import statement to:

```
import StudentNotification from './models/student';
```

Because when you exported it you exported it with the `default` keyword.

```
export default mongoose.model('StudentNotification', StudentSchema);
```